# HTTP basic authentication method to authenticate the mobile client through Datapower

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-datapower

I am using Mobilefirst Platform 8.0 for my app development.

How can we use HTTP basic authentication method to authenticate the mobile client through datapower. Please help me out with challnegHandler sample code.

I tried the below code in challengeHandler but Datapower always returning 401.

```
var DataPowerChallengeHandler = function() {
   var dataPowerChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createGatewayChallengeHandler("LtpaBasedSSO");

   dataPowerChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse = function(response) {
    if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (response.status=="401") {{
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

dataPowerChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
    document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('auth').style.display = 'block';
};

dataPowerChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback = function(response) {
    var isLoginFormResponse = dataPowerChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse(response);
    if (isLoginFormResponse) {
        dataPowerChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(response);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('auth').style.display = 'none';
        dataPowerChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
    }
};

document.getElementById("AuthSubmitButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var username = document.getElementById('txtusername').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;
    var mystring = convertBase64(username+":"+password);
    var headerString = "Basic "+ mystring;
    WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("Authorization",headerString);
    dataPowerChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
});

document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", function() {

    WLAuthorizationManager.logout("LtpaBasedSSO").then(
        function() {
            WL.Logger.debug("logout onSuccess");
            alert("Success logout");
        },
        function(response) {
            WL.Logger.debug("logout onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
});

document.getElementById('AuthCancelButton').addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('auth').style.display = 'none';
  dataPowerChallengeHandler.cancel();
});

return dataPowerChallengeHandler;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gateway challenge handler code is improper and causing all these issues.

`canHandleResponse` method is used to determine whether it is a challenge thrown by datapower or not. Your client code is returning true whenever there is a 401 challenge. This will return true even though for non-datapower challenges which should be corrected.

and `handleChallenge` is explicitly getting called  in `submitLoginFormCallback` method which is wrong. `handleChallenge` will get called by SDK only when `canHandleResponse` method returns true.

Kindly go through [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/datapower-integration/) tutorial for more information on how to use gateway challenge handler in your client application.

Comment: Thanks Vittal for reply. Datapower configured for http basic authentication so it return 401 for every unauthorized request.
The tutorial doed not provide information on  how to do HTTP basic authentication method to authenticate the mobile client through Datapower